# Numbering rows based on logic

Tags: vba, excel

On the left side of below image you see the current state of my Excel sheet.

**Note**: it's all about the *numbering*.

At the moment the numbering is needed to process the sheet. However in a newer version the sheet will look like the right side of the image.

For the new version to work, I'm looking for a macro that will remove the numbers and output the right side of the image.

However if I need to go back to the old version for some reason, I would also like to know how to put the numbering back in there.

[image: Excel sheet with two versions of one table]

Comment: Have you considered normalising the data by filling the Main Category and SubCategory columns down until the row before they change? That's easily done in VBA. You could then build a pivot table with conditional formatting to make JobNo>0 font colour the same as its background colour.

Answer (score 0):

do the below.

```
for i=1 to range("a500000").end(xlup).row

 cells(i,1).select

 if len(selection.offset(0,1))<=1 then
    activecell.value = ""
 end if

 if len(selection.offset(0,3))<=1 then
    activecell.offset(0,2).value = ""
 end if
next i
```

Comment: Why should anyone use this code? You should add an explanation in this answer.

Comment: I was under the impression that the code was self explanatory to the question he asked.

Comment: That's true, but it's better to add a short text to describe what the code do. This way, future users can just go to the solution, understand what the code do and use it. See [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/237701) for details.